# How to play music in all activities in an application?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-mediaplayer

I want to play music in all activities in my app but when i press the button to go to the next activity music stops, i used `onPause()`, onResume and it work properly. I wrote that in other way without `onPause()` and music played in whole app but when i pressed home button music doesn't stop. I used KeyEvent on home button but there is no reaction, i checked it with back and it works but it doesn't minimize app.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution for this is to use [Service](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html). For more info study **MediaPlayer** sample application available in the SDK.